# libevent: как её прилинковать к проекту под Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, компоновщик, libevent

Господа, 
у меня серьезный и важный вопрос, над которым я бьюсь головой об клавиатуру уже больше недели.
Я даже готов обсудить вознаграждение тому, кто мне поможет.
Вопрос такой: надо меня научить правильно ставить галочки в настройках линкера под VS 2015, чтобы у меня библиотека libevent линковалась к проекту на c++ (и, возможно, правильно билдить эту библиотеку).

Предыстория вопроса:
я прочитал пару мотивирующих статей насчет библиотеки libevent 
(напрмер, эту: https://habrahabr.ru/post/217437/ ).
Начал я с того, что сделал девелоперскую машину под Ubuntu 16 LTS,
куда поставл g++ и собрал библиотеку из исходников по иструкциям с гитхаба.
( https://github.com/libevent/libevent )
Потом я написал простую программу test.cpp, в которой попробовал инициализировать библиотеку:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <evhttp.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout<< "Hi!" << endl ;

if ( !event_init()) 
  cout << "Failed to init libevent." << endl;
else
  cout << "libevent init successfully!" << endl;


return 0;
}
```

После небольшого замешательства я нормально собрал эту программу командой 
g++ -std=c++11 -o test.ex  test.cpp -levent
и запустил её.
./test.ex
Всё работает. Это пркрасно.
Затем я переписал из примеров немного более сложный пример...
Но как только я начал писать сам - мне понадобилась отладка.
И родная для меня система в этом смысле - Windows.
Ну, вы понимаете... родственников не выбирают...

А под Windows все совсем не так гладко.
Во первых, нужно собрать библиотеку из исходников.
По инструкции я делаю это при помощи CMake:

```
"CMake (Windows)
Install CMake: http://www.cmake.org

 $ md build && cd build
 $ cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..   # Or whatever generator you want to use
 $ start libevent.sln"
```

Cmake при сборке ругается на отсутствие OpenSSL, и тут уже не помогают никакие танцы с бубнами:
чтобы использовать OpenSSL под виндой, надо определить три магические переменные окружения

```
OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
```

а как эти переменные определять - не написано нигде.
К счастью, если закрыта дверь - можно проверить окно...
libevent позволяет собрать себя без поддержки OpenSSL, дописыванием ключика -DEVENT__DISABLE_OPENSSL=on, 
то есть командой 
cmake -DEVENT__DISABLE_OPENSSL=on -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
Меня, правда, немного смущают некоторые предупреждения, которые написала мне эта команда, 
её вывод видно здесь:
[image: le_pic0.jpg]
Но *.sln файл создаётся, и после запуска компиляции я получил набор *.lib - файлов в директории Debug:
event.lib, event_core.lib, event_extra.lib.
[image: le_pic1.jpg]
А вот потом начались проблемы.
Никакие пляски с бубном не позволяют мне прилинковать эти библиотеки к C++ проекту.
Для полноты картины:
в моей системе путь к этим *.lib файлам - это C:\Programs\includes\libevent\lib\Debug
я засобывал их сюда:
[image: le_pic2.jpg]
и сюда:
[image: le_pic3.jpg]
и сюда:
[image: le_pic4.jpg]
и даже сюда:
[image: le_pic5.jpg]

При последней попытке создалась иллюзия того, что что то получилось. то есть проект нормально собрался. Но при запуске я мгновенно получил ошибку:
[image: le_pic6.jpg]

Потом я сделал еще две жалкие попытки разобраться:
слинковать (потому что сборка obj-файла проходит без ошибок, заметьте) под виндой из командной строки (результат - тот же, не видит библиотеки)
[image: le_pic7.jpg]
и попробовать сравнить содержимой obj - файлов, воспользовавшись под линуксом утилитой nm, а под виндой - dumpbin с опцией /symbols
Но разница слишком велика, я просто вижу в виндовом оьбъектном файле, что символ _event_init - UNDEFined.
[image: le_pic8.jpg]
В общем, я не достиг успеха.
Помогите, пожалуйста, например - подсказав, как определить магические переменные для OpenSSL (может, библиотека толькоприкинулась, что она нормально собрана?),
или попробовав у себя собрать этот проект с этой библиотекой - возможно, у вас получится.

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господа, 
большое спасибо за советы, 
они мне помогли, и особенно мне помогла подсказка на cyberforum.ru.
Итак, я, как человек разумный и уже попробовавший запустить все это под linux и без усилий запустивший - утверждал, что ни о какой специальной инициализации winsock не может быть и речи, ведь библиотека же, в ней внутре всё должно быть сделано! И  именно это своё мнение я писал в ответ на совет что то сделать с winsocket руками.

Оказалось, что я ошибался.

подсказка звучала так:
"Глядите пример libevent/sample/hello-world.c — нужно вызывать."
Точно...
Да, стал сравнивать, и в отдадчике нашел, в каком месте в одном случае инициализация происходит, а в другом — не происходит.
Оказалось, что под виндовс ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО надо в самом начале функции main написать

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    WSAStartup(0x0201, &wsa_data);
#endif
```

Как говорится, никогда не было, и вот опять!

Нет, это никогда не надоедает!

Спасибо всем, кто мне помогал.

( моё личное мнение - о таких вещах надо на каждом заборе писать. чтобы выходишь с работы, видишь забор - а там про винсок под винддовс написано. )

Answer (score 0):

Господа,
у меня появились новые успехи:
как выяснилось, у меня при сборке libevent создаются таки DLL-ки.
Просто я их не сразу заметил.
Сейчас я их копирую в тот же фолдер, где лежит EXEшник.
Сейчас у меня следующая стадия:
программа

```
    #include <memory>
    #include <cstdint>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <evhttp.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        if (!event_init()) {
            cout << "Failed to init libevent." << endl;
        }
        else {

            cout << "Libevent initialised!" << endl;


            char const SrvAddress[] = "192.168.10.53";
            uint16_t SrvPort = 5555;
            unique_ptr<evhttp, decltype(&evhttp_free)> Server(evhttp_start(SrvAddress, SrvPort), &evhttp_free);
            if (!Server)
            {
                cout << "Failed to init http server." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
            void(*OnReq)(evhttp_request *req, void *) = [](evhttp_request *req, void *)
            {
                auto *OutBuf = evhttp_request_get_output_buffer(req);
                if (!OutBuf)
                    return;
                evbuffer_add_printf(OutBuf, "<html><body><center><h1>Hello World! under Windows!</h1></center></body></html>");
                evhttp_send_reply(req, HTTP_OK, "", OutBuf);
            };
            evhttp_set_gencb(Server.get(), OnReq, nullptr);
            if (event_dispatch() == -1)
            {
                cout << "Failed to run messahe loop." << std::endl;
                return -1;

            }
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

собирается и запускается, а после запуска выдаёт ошибку

```
C:\MyProjects\Cpp\LibeEx1\Debug>LibeEx1.exe
[warn] evsig_init_: socketpair: Either the application has not called 
WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed.
Libevent initialised!
[warn] socket: Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or 
WSAStartup failed.
Failed to init http server.
```

после чего завершается.

Comment: дергните WSAStartup ручками. В любом руководстве по winsock сказано, как это делать

Comment: Взял руководство отсюда http://citforum.ru/book/cook/winsock.shtml
Попробовал, но ошибка не изменилась. 
Думаю, что дёрнуть винсок руками из моей программы - не решение, ведь его должна "дёрнуть" библиотека, которую я пытаюсь прилинковать к своему проекту.
К ней винсок2 уже по любому должен быть прилинкован, иначе бы она не собралась.
В общем, пока - непонятно, что делать...

Comment: Я прошел в дебаге до той строки, в которой программа не может создать сокет.
На картинке видно, какие значения имели переменные в момент, когда сокет не смог создаться.
Посмотрите, может, в чем то понятном дело?
http://junecat.ru/Storage/oth/le_pic11.jpg

Comment: @KoVadim, но разве Libevent - сам не должен вызывать WSAStartup  ?

Comment: @Optimus1 - с тех пор, как я несколько лет назад ("еще зеленым юнцом") задал этот вопрос, я несколько раз сталкивался с работй с сокетами, и везде под виндой нужно было WSAStartup вызывать вручную. Но это - мой опыт :-)

Comment: @S.H., если вы работаете на прямую с Winsock, то да, но я почему то думал, что Libebevent - сама внутри должна инициализировать необходимую сетевую библиотеку операционной системы.

Comment: @Optimus1 - даже в минимальных примерах https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/sample/hello-world.c вызывают. Как по мне, то это дело дизайна библиотеки - вызывать или нет. Тут решили, что не нужно. Имеют право.

Comment: @Optimus1 - думаю, что в сокращенном виде сомнения на тему "должна ли  Libebevent сама инициализировать необходимую сетевую библиотеку" сводятся к "отличию библиотеки от фремворка" - эта тема иногда обсуждается, например, здесь:  https://qna.habr.com/q/99107

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, да, в примере я этой части не приметил. Но, чисто теоретически - а были ли или есть ли сложность - эту инициализацию запихнуть в сами исходники Libevent ?

Comment: а смысл ее туда пихать? я вообще не понимаю, зачем в винде нужен это WSAStartup. Можно было бы и без него.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну смысл в том, что бы платформо-зависимого кода не писать, даже, если это несколько строчек. Ну какая разница зачем он винде, так реализовали, имеют право.

Comment: Я думал над вопросом и возможно, wsastartup нельзя вызывать дважды и тогда все стает на свои места